# What is the best way to represent binary data?

Tags: reporting-services, graph, powerbi, data-analysis

I am trying to plot a graph in powerBi, Having DateTime vs state,
Which would be a better way to represent the data.

Presently, I have tried Line Graph and Area Plot, Both look bad as we have more fluctuations in the state values.

The following is the sample of the data:-

```
xDate           IsHealthy
5/26/2017 12:31 TRUE
5/26/2017 12:41 FALSE
5/26/2017 12:51 FALSE
5/26/2017 13:01 FALSE
5/26/2017 13:11 TRUE
5/26/2017 13:21 FALSE
5/26/2017 13:31 FALSE
5/26/2017 13:41 FALSE
5/26/2017 13:51 TRUE
5/26/2017 14:01 FALSE
5/26/2017 14:11 TRUE
```

Please suggest a better way to get more insights out of the above data

Comment: The best answer to this will depend significantly on what insights you are looking to gain, the accompanying information that is on your report/dashboard alongside this chart.  That said, what is wrong with a simple column chart with either different colours for `IsHealthy` or casting to a positive/negative value?

Comment: We basically want to have a overview of the service availability ,and from a very broader perspective. And We don't want to read logs, rather Graph should be self explanatory .

Comment: Then experiment with the different graph/chart types until you find something that fits your expectations.

Answer (score 0):

I would group the data by date then count of TRUE and FALSE. Assuming this is some kind of 'up-time availability report' then calculate the percentage of up-time based on the number of samples per day.

I've converted the TRUE/FALSE to bit types and included sample data so you can test quickly.

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (xDate datetime, IsHealthy bit)
INSERT into @t
VALUES 
('5/26/2017 12:31', 1),
('5/26/2017 12:41', 0), 
('5/26/2017 12:51', 0), 
('5/26/2017 13:01', 0), 
('5/26/2017 13:11', 1), 
('5/26/2017 13:21', 0), 
('5/26/2017 13:31', 0), 
('5/26/2017 13:41', 0), 
('5/26/2017 13:51', 1), 
('5/26/2017 14:01', 0), 
('5/26/2017 14:11', 1),

('5/27/2017 12:31', 1),
('5/27/2017 12:41', 1), 
('5/27/2017 12:51', 1), 
('5/27/2017 13:01', 0), 
('5/27/2017 13:11', 1), 
('5/27/2017 13:21', 1), 
('5/27/2017 13:31', 1), 
('5/27/2017 13:41', 0), 
('5/27/2017 13:51', 1), 
('5/27/2017 14:01', 0)

select distinct
    convert(date, xDate) as xDate, IsHealthy
    , count(*) over (PARTITION BY convert(date, xDate), IsHealthy) as CountPerState
    , count(*) over (PARTITION BY convert(date, xDate)) as TotalCOuntPerDay
    , CAST(count(*) over (PARTITION BY convert(date, xDate), IsHealthy) as float) / cast(count(*) over (PARTITION BY convert(date, xDate)) as float) as PercentageOfDay
from @t
```

This gives you the following output

```
xDate       IsHealthy   CountPerState   TotalCOuntPerDay    PercentageOfDay
2017-05-26  0           7               11                  0.636363636363636
2017-05-26  1           4               11                  0.363636363636364
2017-05-27  0           3               10                  0.3
2017-05-27  1           7               10                  0.7
```

Now you have this you could plot just the `PercentageOfDay` where `IsHealthy=1` rows as a line or show both states in a stacked column depending on which you prefer.

Comment: Thanks Alan, But this information in PowerBi can be easily plotted in pie chart and a date slicer, That would not only give day wise insights but also it would help us dive into time of the day aswell.

Comment: Oops! That will teach me to have more than 3 hours sleep! I hope it at least have you some more ideas for the visualisation side of things anyway.